# How can I pass list of values from c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, arraylist, marshalling

I want to pass list of array values from c++ to c#. So how can I pass it ? When I use datatype as struct in c++ it throws Error.

> 3   error C2562: 'xxx' : 'void' function returning a value
>   C# code
>   enter code here

```
    struct ValuesMethod
    {
        ValuesMethod(char* a, int b) {

            Value = a;
            Confidence = b;
        }
        char* Value;
        int Confidence;
    };
    extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) vector<ValuesMethod> _stdcall  FetchList(char* SourceImgeFileName, char* BackImageFileName, char DataFolderName[]){
        map<long, int> Employees;
        std::vector<ValuesMethod> stc;
    return stc;
    }
```

C# Code

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ValuesMethod
        {
           IntPtr Value;
           public string sAsString { get { return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Value); } }

           //public string Value;
            public int Confidence;

        };
    [DllImport("Mydll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   //[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public static extern List<ValuesMethod> FetchList(string SourceImageFileName, string BackImageFileName, string DataFolderName);
```

Comment: struct ValuesMethod
{

 ValuesMethod(char* a, int b) {

  Value = a;
  Confidence = b;
 }
 char* Value;
 int Confidence;
};



extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) vector<ValuesMethod> _stdcall  FetchList(char* SourceImgeFileName, char* BackImageFileName, char DataFolderName[]){std::vector<ValuesMethod> stc; return stc;}

Comment: not here...but in question you posted.

Comment: hi Rakitic i Mentioned the code there